# How to send message with discord.js with ID

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a command than reply in DM hello to the author if just saying !hello but DM someone if !hello @someone.

```
if (message.content.includes("@"))
        {
            var str = message.content.split("@")
            var name = str[1]
            name = name.replace("!","<") // doing that I got the ID <18 numbers>
            message.name.send("Hello you")
        }
        else
            message.author.send('Hello')
```

But I can't use name like this, how can I take the username and use it with send afterwards ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

```
if(message.mentions.users.size > 0) {
message.mentions.users.first().send('Hello you');
}
```

message.mentions.users is a collection of users that are mentioned, so this calls the first user in that list and sends the message to them.